# ggplot: geom_text over geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
foo = read.table(text="
protein1    1.51E-02    5   label1
protein2    9.06E-05    850 label2
protein3    3.38E-05    1155    label1
protein4    3.38E-05    1154    label1
protein5    6.64E-03    35  label3
protein6    5.32E-03    44  label4",
sep="\t", col.names=c("category", "value", "rank", "ToLabel"))
```

And I want to make a bar plot of `rank` (x axis) vs. `value` (y axis), and add a label that is stored in the column `ToLabel`.

This is my code for plotting:

```
ggplot(data=foo, aes(x=rank, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_col(fill="dark grey") +
  labs(x = "Rank",
       y = "Value") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual( values = c( "yes"="red", "no"="black" ), guide = "none" ) +
  geom_pointrange(data = foo, aes(x=rank, y=value, ymin = 0, ymax = 0)) +
  #geom_text(data = genes_df, aes(x=rank, y=relative_iBAQ, label = ToText), vjust = 0, angle=45, size = 1)
  geom_text(data = foo, aes(label = ToLabel), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 1.1), angle=45, size = 3)
```

Unfortunately, the labels are not positioned inside my plotting area:
[image]

I have so far not found a way to move them. Any idea how to position the labels better?

Comment: Either get rid of the `expand(0, 0)` for the x scale so there's a bit of padding or manually adjust them.

Comment: And it doesn't seem like you need `position = position_stack(vjust = 1.1)`. I'd delete that and use `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` instead to adjust all of them.

Comment: Yes, `nudge` is what I was looking for. However, it takes the center of the label as a reference point, any way of taking the leftmost position as a reference?

Comment: Also use `hjust` (for horizontal justification). `hjust = 0` should make the leftmost point of the label as the reference.

Comment: Ok great, I need both `hjust = 0` and `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`. Thank you! (also, if you make a regular answer I could thank you by rewarding you :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` arguments to adjust the text, but you have to stop using `position` for that to work. See the `?geom_text` help page for details.

I'd also recommend not using `expand(0, 0)` for the x-axis so there's a bit of padding where your labels can go.

And you can control the justification of the text with `hjust`. The default `hjust = 0.5` centers the text on its coordinate. Setting `hjust = 0` left justifies the text at its coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

I added xlim and ylim values. But you don't need to do this if you remove expand(0,0) Thomas noted.

```
xlim(-100, 1100) +
ylim(-.001, .02)
```

[image]